# Reflection: can't get a MethodInfo for 'Add' in class BindingList<> if the type argument is a TypeBuilder

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, reflection.emit, typebuilder

We have a compiler that uses reflection emit to generate assemblies. We have stumbled with trying to obtain the MethodInfo for the Add method in the `BindingList<T>` class, when T is a TypeBuilder object. We are using `TypeBuilder.GetMethod( typeof(BindingList<myTypeBuilder>), typeof(BindingList<T>).GetMethod( "Add" ))` but it throws an ArgumentException: "The specified method cannot be dynamic or global and must be declared on a generic type definition." Are we doing anything wrong? This works for List. Another observation, `typeof( List<> ).GetMethod( "Add" ).DeclaringType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` is true, while 
`typeof( BindingList<> ).GetMethod( "Add" ).DeclaringType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` is false, which doesn't make sense to me.

Here's C# code that recreates the issue

```
var assemblyBuilder = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly( new AssemblyName("MyAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save, "C:\\output\\" );
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule( "MyModule", "MyModule.dll", false );
// create MyClass in the module
TypeBuilder myClass = moduleBuilder.DefineType( "MyClass" );
Type bindingListOfT = typeof( BindingList<> );
Type bindingListOfMyClass = bindingListOfT.MakeGenericType( myClass );
// create the DoStuff method in MyClass
MethodBuilder doStuffMethod = myClass.DefineMethod( "DoStuff", MethodAttributes.Private );
ILGenerator generator = doStuffMethod.GetILGenerator();
// var myList = new BindingList<MyClass>()
LocalBuilder myListDeclaration = generator.DeclareLocal( bindingListOfMyClass );
ConstructorInfo listOfMyClassConstructor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor( bindingListOfMyClass,
    bindingListOfT.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) );
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, listOfMyClassConstructor );
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc, myListDeclaration );
// myList.Add( new MyClass() )
ConstructorInfo myClassConstructor = myClass.DefineConstructor( MethodAttributes.Public,
    CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes );
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, myListDeclaration );
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, myClassConstructor );
// the next line throws exception. If using List<> instead on BindingList<> all is well

MethodInfo add1 = TypeBuilder.GetMethod( bindingListOfMyClass, bindingListOfT.GetMethod( "Add" ) );
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Callvirt, add1 );

// finish
generator.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
myClass.CreateType();
assemblyBuilder.Save( "MyModule.dll", PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly, ImageFileMachine.I386 );
```

We have found a workaround which involves getting the declaring type's generic type definition, finding the MethodInfo in this type, making a generic type out of the generic type definition, and then calling TypeBuilder.GetMethod. It's a horrible piece of code, as first we need to find the correct MethodInfo not only based on name but also on arguments, and then climb back the inheritance chain of the original type so we can correctly match the type arguments in the base class to call MakeGenericType, all the way back to the method's declaring type. There has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add` is actually declared on `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<>`, so try using that type instead of `BindingList<>` when creating your two `Type` instances.

**EDIT**

As to why `BindingList<T>`'s base class is not a generic type definition, it's a bit subtle.  While the base class is `Collection<T>`, the `T` is actually different from the `T` used in `Collection<T>`'s definition (it's the `T` declared as part of `BindingList<T>`'s definition).  Perhaps an easier-to-grasp example would be something along these lines:

```
class SameTypeDict<T> : Dictionary<T,T> {}
```

Here, `SameTypeDict<T>`'s base class is `Dictionary<T,T>`, which is different from the generic type definition `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

I think something along these lines should do what you want:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a concrete generic type instantiation T&lt;t_1, t_2, ...>, where any number of the t_i may be type builders,
/// and given a method M on the generic type definition T&lt;>, return the corresponding method on the concrete type
/// </summary>
static MethodInfo GetConcreteMethodInfo(Type concreteClass, MethodInfo genericTypeMethod)
{
    var substitution = concreteClass.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()
                        .Zip(concreteClass.GetGenericArguments(), (t1, t2) => Tuple.Create(t1, t2))
                        .ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
    var declaredMethod = genericTypeMethod.DeclaringType.Module.ResolveMethod(genericTypeMethod.MetadataToken);
    var declaringTypeGeneric = declaredMethod.DeclaringType;  // typeof(Collection<>)
    var declaringTypeRelative = genericTypeMethod.DeclaringType; // typeof(Collection<BindingList<T>.T>)
    // now get the concrete type by applying the substitution
    var declaringTypeConcrete = // typeof(Collection<myClass>)
        declaringTypeGeneric.MakeGenericType(Array.ConvertAll(declaringTypeRelative.GetGenericArguments(),
                                                t => substitution.ContainsKey(t) ? substitution[t] : t));
    return TypeBuilder.GetMethod(declaringTypeConcrete, (MethodInfo)declaredMethod);
}
```

Note that you may need to make some modifications if the method itself can also be generic.

Comment: Hi @kvb, I figured out as much (maybe my workaround description is not too clear, because I need a solution that can be generally applicable, not only to this method and class). What I don't understand is why this is needed, and why if I'm getting `Add` out of a generic type definition (`BindingList<T>`) the MethodInfo object I get is 'crippled', i.e. its declaring type is _not_ a generic type definition.

Comment: Thanks @kvb, I like your solution. Much cleaner than my horribly convoluted code :) though I still think `TypeBuilder.GetMethod` should be able to handle this case itself.

Comment: I agree that that would be desirable.  Unfortunately the specification of the method seems to indicate that the current behavior is expected.